# Differences between Dynamic Regression Model and Intervention Model?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, forecasting, intervention-analysis, dynamic-regression

I am currently studying on dynamic regression and intervention model but I haven't have much resources on hand about the differentiating both of them. I understand that intervention model is a special type of dynamic regression model and one of the difference is instead of having some independent variables like the dynamic regression which depends on the times series where x can be anything, intervention model has independent variable that is limited to O and 1.

What are some other differences that they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both models apply the transfer function, (), to a variable. And they both take into account noise as . Hence, they are both transfer function-noise models.

However, while the standard dynamic regression model applies the transfer function to an independent variable, , make a better forecast of the dependent variables, an intervention model is a special form of dynamic regression model that instead applies the transfer function to indicator variable that describes the event, (). The indicator variable helps to measure the impact of the event on the response variable.

P.s. Good luck for TOA tmr!